# Decrypting keys at the software application level

Tags: encryption, software

Does anyone know what the most common method of decrypting data is? I.e., if something is hashed and not decrypted at the firewall, how is it usually decrypted within a system?

Is it integrated into source code?

Comment: @kpipeline: Welcome. This will explain you in easy, how encryption works: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33949/htg-explains-what-is-encryption-and-how-does-it-work/ . In general, if you encrypt data with X method, you need X method to decrypted. The term "hash" is usually associated with one-way encryption which means you can not get wood from charcoal. Firewalls do not decrypt or encrypt information. There is plenty of information about that already.

Comment: Yes.... However say I am trying to decrypt a message (that has been encrypted using a private key) using a public key.

Comment: Where is the public key stored usually ? Within the application layer of a software application?

Comment: kpipeline - your question is very confusing. Can you edit it and try to better explain the scenario you are dealing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question rightly then you are mostly right, dealing with OSI layer encryption/decryption usually happens in the upper layers which are session, presentation and application.

These layers are most often merged within the actual software logic (they will all be part the same single software), where you will find TLS tunneling right at the bottom of the session layer, and more custom data encryption usage somewhere in the presentation and application layers (from a pure OSI perspective, it would be merely presentation layer if encryption is disconnected from your core application logic, ie. the actual service you provide, but at the end it may depend what your application does and how you built it.).